# Finding uncertainty in coefficients from polyfit in Matlab (no Toolboxes)

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, computational-statistics

I have a data set of x- and y-values, that I want make a linear fit of. Using `polyfit(x,y,1)` I get the coefficients `a` and `b` for a linear fit `ax = b` for this data, but I would also like to find the uncertainty or standard deviation for these coefficients. Does anyone know an easy way of doing this?

My Google-fu only gave me [this](http://www.mathworks.se/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/103667) result, and seeing as the last answer in that thread is a correction to first answer, I don't know if I should trust any of the answers. The answer from that thread is:

```
[z,s]=polyfit(x,y,1);
ste = sqrt(diag(inv(s.R)*inv(s.R')).*s.normr.^2./s.df);
```

Here is the data set if anyone needs it:

```
x = [1.3979 1.6990 2.0000 2.3010 2.6021 2.9031];
y = [-1.5219 -1.6300 -1.8249 -2.2584 -2.5054 -2.6248];
```

(I realize it looks more like a third order polynomial, but they should be linear according to the theory behind my measurements.)

Answer (score 1):

So My code would be like this:

```
x = [1.3979 1.6990 2.0000 2.3010 2.6021 2.9031]';
y = [-1.5219 -1.6300 -1.8249 -2.2584 -2.5054 -2.6248]';
% cftool(x,y)
ft_ = fittype('poly3'); 
[myfit, mygof, myout] = fit(x,y,ft_)
```

note that the variation is stored in "myfit".  You can break open each of the output structures to determine what is inside as follows:

```
struct(myfit)
struct(mygof)
struct(myout)
```

Using the CF-tool I found the following.

```
Linear model Poly3:;
f(x) = p1*x^3 + p2*x^2 + p3*x + p4 Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
p1 =      0.7967  (-0.1607, 1.754)
p2 =      -5.192  (-11.38, 0.9965)
p3 =        10.1  (-2.85, 23.05)
p4 =      -7.678  (-16.42, 1.068)

Goodness of fit:
SSE: 0.004777
R-square: 0.9956
Adjusted R-square: 0.989
RMSE: 0.04887
```

Here are the first order results:

```
Linear model Poly1:
f(x) = p1*x + p2
Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
p1 =     -0.8138  (-1.024, -0.604)
p2 =     -0.3109  (-0.7748, 0.1531)

Goodness of fit:
SSE: 0.03623
R-square: 0.9667
Adjusted R-square: 0.9583
RMSE: 0.09517
```

Here is a graph:
[image: Graph of fits and errors]

I suggest using AICc and being willing to believe that your derivation might have assumptions of linearity that are not entirely correct.  More samples might help, even samples at the same points.